# Create a custom xml drawable with dynamic colour

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a custom radio button in Android with below custom drawable background:

[image]

I am able to create different drawables for selected and unselected. Below is the xml drawable, when selected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff207d94"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
            android:width="9dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ff207d94"/>
        <size
            android:width="7dp"
            android:height="7dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

The requirement I have is to change the colour of the selected radio button dynamically, ie., the border and the solid colour inside should be the same. With the current xml, I am not able to achieve this, because item1 has #ff207d94 colour as stroke, whereas item2 has #ff207d94 colour as solid.

I am not able to find an exact solution to this problem anywhere. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.drawable_res);
GradientDrawable gradient = (GradientDrawable) shape.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.item_id);
gradient.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color_res));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. For some reasons, on first click, the colour of the radio button was net set properly. I just had to change to `LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) getButtonDrawable();`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is helpful to you?

---

1. First, add the drawable file checkbox_style.xml to the drawable folder.

```
    <？xml version =“1.0”encoding =“utf-8”？> 
    <selector xmlns：android =“http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”> 
        <item android：drawable =“@ drawable / checkbox_pressed“android：state_checked =”true“/> 
        <item android：drawable =”@ drawable / checkbox_normal“android：state_checked =”false“/> 
        <item android：drawable =”@ drawable / checkbox_normal“/> 
    </ selector >
```

2. Add the CustomCheckboxTheme style to the styles.xml file in the values folder.

```
    <style name =“CustomCheckboxTheme”parent =“@ android：style / Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox”>
```

3. Use the CustomCheckboxTheme style in the layout file.

```
    <CheckBox 
        android：id =“@ + id / select_all” 
        android：layout_width =“wrap_content” 
        android：layout_height =“wrap_content” 
        style =“@ style / CustomCheckboxTheme”/>
```

---

Author: snail
Source: CSDN
original: HTTPS：//blog.csdn.net/zuolongsnail/article/details/7106586